# Xml attribute accessing using linq?

Tags: linq-to-xml

In xml document how can i get the value of  attribute.
My query what i write now.

```
 var query = from r in document.Descendants("User")                       
                    where (string)r.Element("Reply") == ""
                    select new
                    {
                        SendBy = r.Element("SendBy").Value,                            
                        Messages = r.Element("Messages").Value,
                        Reply = r.Element("Reply").Value,
                        Senddate = r.Element("SentDate").Value,
                        MessageId = r.Attribute ("MessageId").Value 
                    };
```

I am gettng object reference instance of an object error.

Comment: Most likely one of the elements you're looking for isn't there.  Using `(string)r.Element("SendBy")` or `(string)r.Attribute("MessageId")` will return null if the element/attribute specified isn't present.  Other than that, post the XML you're trying to parse - there's not much we can tell you without more context.

Comment: i think attribute("MessageId") when i remove that i am getting the result but i need Attribute("MessageId")

Comment: Then the attribute "MessageId" isn't there - it's either not in the XML, it has a different casing (XML is case-sensitive), or it's not an attribute on "User".  Unless you post the XML, it's nearly impossible to give you a more precise answer.